# Hide minutes in TChart components

Tags: delphi, teechart

How can I hide time (hour, minutes and sec) in TChart component? 
Need only Date format.

Set

```
Chart1.BottomAxis.DateTimeFormat := GetLocaleShortDateFormat(); {MMM/yy/dd},
```

but time is present in chart

Comment: how about Chart1.BottomAxis.DateTimeFormat := 'MMM/YY/DD' ?

Comment: @Hendra, capital letters or not, works both ways. See my answer. Zooming in on one day still gets only date format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example how to use TeeChart.

Add a TChart component and a TButton on a form, include unit Series and add this code on the button `OnClick` event:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  S1: TLineSeries;
  i,j: integer;
begin
  Chart1.View3D := false;
  Chart1.SeriesList.Clear;
  S1 := TLineSeries.Create(Self);
  S1.XValues.DateTime := True;  
  Chart1.BottomAxis.DateTimeFormat := 'MMM/YY/DD';  //Works with 'MMM/yy/dd' also
  Chart1.AddSeries(S1);
  for i := 0 to 10 do
    for j := 0 TO 23 do
    S1.AddXY(Trunc(Now) + i + j/24.0, Random(100)/10.0 + i*10.0);
end;
```

And this is the result:
[image]

I could not reproduce the behaviour in the question, with different settings of the `DateTimeFormat`.